# Ctypes callback being ignored

Tags: python, python-2.7, callback, ctypes

I have a c callback with the following prototype:

```
typedef void (* FrameDataCallBack)( TProcessedDataProperty* Attributes, unsigned char *BytePtr );
```

This callback function is meant to be user-defined, and attached to a camera with the following function.

```
BUFCCDUSB_InstallFrameHooker( int FrameType, FrameDataCallBack FrameHooker );
```

I have tried prototyping the callback multiple ways:

1.

```
def frame_callback(attributes, frame):
for i in xrange(480*640): #Reads bytes and stores them in an array for future use
    frame_buffer[i/640][i%640] = frame[i*config.bin_no]
print "hi"
CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, 
                           ctypes.POINTER(TProcessedDataProperty), 
                           ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))(frame_callback)
```

2.

```
CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, 
                       ctypes.POINTER(TProcessedDataProperty), 
                       ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
@CMPFUNC
def frame_callback....
#function declaration
```

3.

```
CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, 
                           ctypes.POINTER(TProcessedDataProperty), 
                           ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
cbfunc = CMPFUNC(frame_callback)
```

I then try to attach the callback with

```
BUFCCDUSB_InstallFrameHooker(0, CMPFUNC):   (frame_callback and cb for the respective callback codes)
```

after instantiating the correct arg and restypes for the function, however the callback is never called. I was hoping someone could point me towards any possible errors

Comment: Hello frank_x, I am trying to do some programming in python for mightex cameras. Would you mind sharing your code with me? I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've addressed that at the bottom. For future reference for anyone working with Mightex Cameras, it appears that their callback needs to be attached to a GUI. I attached sections of code to Tkinter buttons, and the callback works perfectly.

Comment: The callback function needs to be referenced to keep it alive, like any other Python object. This has nothing to do with being attached to a GUI.

Comment: The callback function was properly referenced, no? Both the first and the third method should keep it alive. I'm 99% sure it has to do with the camera requiring a window, Looking thru the sample C code seems to back this up.

Comment: I don't see how attaching it to a GUI element changes anything. The callback is a structure with a reference to a Python function and information about the input and output datatypes. The C code never sees this directly. It sees an ffi wrapper that calls another wrapper in ctypes that calls your Python function.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but I didn't touch my callback at all, and the code works now, so I can't complain.